# Convert .htaccess rule to the correct Nginx one

Tags: linux, nginx, .htaccess

Good day,

I've just installed a simple url shortener script on my website, unfortunately the author is not able to give me advice for Nginx since he wrote the script with Apache and mod_rewrite in his mind, so many url rewrites are not correctly interpreted.

I've tried to use the online .htaccess to Nginx converters, but the resulting code, is not working.

## This is the orginal .htacces file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{request_filename} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(([^/]*)+)(/([^/]{0,32})(/.+)?)?$  index.php?a=$1&q=$3    [L]
```

And this is the converted code from some automated converter, but is not working

## nginx configuration

```
location / {
if (-e $request_filename){
rewrite ^/(.*) /$1 break;
}
rewrite "^/(([^/]*)+)(/([^/]{0,32})(/.+)?)?$" /index.php?a=$1&q=$3 break;
}
```

Comment: what is the output of nginx log file? thats the first step I would take in figuring out how nginx is interpreting the URLs

Comment: I noticed in the errors the links are pointing to /var/www/web/stats (for example) but the correct path is /var/www/stats without the "web" part

Comment: `if (-e $request_filename){` online "convert apache to nginx" scripts are not worth using and best avoided. [try_files](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) is a better choice than that. Also `rewrite ^/(.*) /$1 break;` - that's a weird rule - you should probably delete that, it's not doing anything except [preventing the next rewrite rule from being reachable](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#break).

Comment: @AD7six following your advice i put the last rewrite rule in the vhost conf.  At least now I get a 404 page :-)